# Is a pcp air gun allowed on a flight to Indonesia

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, indonesia, firearms

I want to buy a pcp air rifle from Miami. Is it allow to be carried in to my checked luggage on a flight to Indonesia?

I need to buy one for taking care of wild hogs on my farm in Indonesia.

Comment: Do you think a PCP air rifle (usually used for hunting animals like rabbits) will have any effect on a wild hog?

Comment: They would have to be some very small wild hogs.

Comment: Or a very large air gun.  There's really no limit to air guns, they have air guns that can launch F-14 Tomcats.  That'll handle the really big boar!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking air rifles are allowed in checked baggage, but special precautions need to be taken - usually including special packing and making sure the cylinder is fully discharged. You may need to notify the airline in advance, and turn up early to check your baggage in. Check with your airline for what you need to do.

You should also check what permits etc. are required for importing and owning a PCP airgun in Indonesia. Many countries require them to be licensed.